How can I have a table from workspace as input to a Function Caller block
I have a table stored in the workspace. For this table I have defined several functions to read and post process the data contained in this table.
Some of these functions I want to use in a Simulink mode.
My current approach is to use a Function Caller block inside my simulink model that gets as input a source "from Workspace" block. However this generates an error message that this input format is unsupported and that I should only use supported format such as timeseries etc.
However, my function is heavily built around the table structure calling upon the variable names in the table.
Is there another way to get the table from the workspace in its proper table format as input to the Function Caller?
